# Change text in regex to upper-case

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem. How can I change text between "<" and ">" (HTML tags), to upper-case letters?
Part of code:

```
string a= @"<html><b>hello world!</b>
<table>test</table></html>";
a = Regex.Replace(a, @"<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty);
```

Now, output is:

```
hello world!
test
```

And I want to have:

```
<HTML><B>hello world!</B>
<TABLE>test</TABLE></HTML>
```

I know that String.Empty delete code between < >, but how to change this text to upper-case letters? Just give me some advice, how to do it.

Greetings!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = Regex.Replace(a, @"<(.|\n)*?>", m=>m.Value.ToUpper());
```

Comment: great ! but can you tell me, what means this part of code?
`m=>m.Value.ToUpper()` ? What is "m"?

Comment: `m`is the `Match` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx). So the lambda `m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant()` would return the matched text, upper-cased.

Comment: @whoah exactly equals to `delegate(Match m) { return m.Value.ToUpper(); }`