# C# String Comparison Ignore Case Sensitivity HTML Tags

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I have to compare 2 strings that have HTML tags in them. I'd like to ignore the casing of the HTML tags themselves, but DO compare the casing of the other strings outside of HTML tags. Would like some help in coding this logic.
For example, I want to ignore the casing of the TD tags in the strings below.

```
String1: "<td>this is case-sensitive</td>"

String2: "<TD>THIS is CASE-sensitive</TD>"
```

Comment: you need to respond to the answers otherwise how will they know what are you looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Regex class then do a comparison.

So following your example you could do the following:

```
var string1 = "<td>This is case-sensitive</td>";
var string2 = "<TD>This is case-Sensitive</TD>";

var regex = new Regex("<[^>]*>");

Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(string1, "") == regex.Replace(string2, ""));
//Result is False
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out!

Comment: Sorry I'm not too fluent with Regex, but how can I do a ToUpper or ToLower on the strings between the chevrons rather than replacing them with ""? The reason is I do want to compare their content (just not the casing). In your example, I wouldn't be able to catch if the tags don't match.

Comment: [Obligatory link to answer about using Regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I found this post which does what I need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140456/change-text-in-regex-to-upper-case. Thanks for the pointer Daniel!

Comment: No problem Angie, glad to have helped!

Answer (score -2):

```
 string str = "<td>This is case Sensitive</td>";
            str = Regex.Replace(str, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
            Console.Write(str);
```

This Might Work for you

Comment: @mason i think it has to be generic for all tags

Comment: Why would you perform a string contains? Why not simply do the replacement call and move on? And how would this work if the tag was something besides `<td>`? Would you have to create a list of all HTML tags?

Comment: In my example I only have TD, but it can contain any HTML tags. Unless I collect the entire library of all HTML tags, this won't work for me.

Comment: ok in that case you can use This     str = Regex.Replace(str, "<.*?>", String.Empty);

Comment: I don't want to replace them with String.Empty since I'll miss the actual tag value. How can I convert them to all upper or lower case?

Comment: why dont you use .ToUpper() or .ToLower() function of string to change case like     str = str.ToLower();   try it out